# change the location of the .nextflow folder?

Tags: nextflow

when I run nextflow, I get a `.nextflow` folder, but I can't find a way to change its location (i.e. it is't `-work-dir`). How can I change the location of the `.nextflow` folder?

I have looked at `launchDir` but it seems that is a read-only implicit variable and cannot be overwritten in the CLI, also, the `--launchDir` option is only valid for the k8s scope (see original chat in [gitter](https://matrix.to/#/!ePFrrbtpbAvsZdwlbH:gitter.im/$OMyE9wT409E0HvR8Q3DZWteeRi4rhdRrqG_sjmI7rXM?via=gitter.im&via=matrix.org&via=enactive.net))

I'm using Nextflow 20.10.0 build 5430.

Comment: The `.nextflow` cache directory stores things like the Nextflow CacheDB and plugins (symlinks to the parent repository) for each Nextflow instance. I don't think there's a way to change the parent path of this directory, without changing directories beforehand. I wonder if this is an XY problem?

Comment: (i had to look up what an 'XY problem' is)... I have an app that embeds nextflow and during unit and integration tests, I get `.nextflow` folders scattered in the project and tests folder; I want to control the location of the `.nextflow` folders to keep things tidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping things neat and tidy is admirable. From [this comment](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/1747#issuecomment-706042687), it looks like the only way (without doing crazy things...) is to change to the directory you want your `.nextflow` cache directory to live and point all other options (i.e. `-work-dir`, `-log` etc) away to a separate directory:

> If you want `.nextflow` in dir A and the pipeline work dir in B:
>
> ```
> cd A
> nextflow run -w B
> ```
>
> The `.nextflow` has to be in the launching
> directory to properly maintain the history of the executions.